# How do I implement this in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am using this query directly and want to use ActiveRecord,

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM p
       LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT pid
             FROM s LEFT JOIN i ON s.key = i.sid
            WHERE i.default = 'y') AS table_x
       ON p.pid = table_x.pid WHERE isnull(table_x.pid) AND p.show = 'y'
```

But I am not quite sure how to implement the above. The definition I have so far is below.

```
class P < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :s, :foreign_key => 'pid'
  has_many :i, :through => :s
end


class S < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :p, :foreign_key => 'pid' 
  has_many :i, :foreign_key => 'sid' 
end

class I < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :s, :foreign_key => 'sid'
  belongs_to :p, :through => :s
end
```

The part I am keen to know is on how to create/bring the subselect as a table/model?

Comment: Is pid defined on table s or i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue here is that you are trying to perform a join on tables based on column (`pid`) which you are asking to be null.  You cannot join on NULL values.  However, if that was a mistake and you do *not* want to join on NULL `pid` values, then an equivalent SQL statement would be as follows (assuming that the `s` table contains `pid`, not `i`):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM p 
LEFT JOIN s ON s.pid=p.pid 
LEFT JOIN i ON s.key=i.sid 
WHERE i.default='y' AND p.show = 'y'
```

This query very easily translates to ActiveRecord as you can then simply use the `.joins()` method concatenated by a `.where()` method.  Maybe something like this could work for you:

```
P.joins(:s => :i).where('i.default = ?', 'y').where('p.show = ?', 'y').count()
```